# freeMode not working on Swiper inside an inner slide

Tags: javascript, swiper.js

I have a very simple issue that I can't figure out whether I'm doing something wrong or if it's an issue from the library itself. I'm scratching my head for hours on this.

I'm using [Swiper](http://www.idangero.us/swiper/#.VlwVs6Jqvsl) from iDangerous.

I'm trying to create a simple Horizontal Swiper and inside each slide, there will be another slider which will be in vertical mode and **I need to have that vertical slider in freeMode**. That inner vertical slider will always have one slide having lots of content (at least some, that can be scrolled). **The nested scroller works but the freeMode is not working for me at all**. freeMode is only working if I declare it on the outer one. I have a fiddle in place so you can see what I'm trying to do. Some sample code from the fiddle is as follows.

### HTML

```
<div class="swiper-container outer">
            <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                <div class="swiper-slide">

                    <div class="swiper-container inner">
                        <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                            <div class="swiper-slide">
                                lots of lorem ipsum here. see fiddle
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
                <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
                <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
                <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 5</div>
                <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 6</div>
                <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 7</div>
                <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 8</div>
                <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 9</div>
                <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 10</div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

### Javascript

```
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container.outer');
var swiper1 = new Swiper('.swiper-container.inner', {
    direction: 'vertical',
    freeMode: true
});
```

### Fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/sdugx1Lu/

Any help is greatly appreciated.

### Update

My original intention is not at all in favor of using nested sliders. What I actually want to accomplish is to have vertically scrollable content (via touch, I'm using it in an app) inside Horizontal slider through Swiper. So, if this can be accomplished without using the second level of nested slider, please do suggest. As when I tried to do that, the vertical scroll was not available in case of single level horizontal slider.

Answer (score 0):

```
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1>
</head>
```

This line make your code adjust to mobile, and also will make the `width` become `device-width`.

But your height is 100% and you can't change if you don't

so when you change your style in your css file, maybe it will be used in every section (container) if you don't add that line of code.

but you add that line of code every section will become :height is device-height,

so what you should is add special style in your css file for which you want change

such as your article is longer than device-height, you have to add special style for that section. if not, your scroll will not working.

Chinese: I want to print Chinese, but not allowed.